# Set the default value of an input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my requirement is to save the entire "html" inside a div, but when i load an "html" with text fields to a div and then editing the value of the text box, the newly set value doesn't reflect in the core "html". I tried to inspect the value with fire bug and it remains the  same or no value at all.With "jquery" i tried  to set attribute but no attribute name value is created. how can i set the value of text fields and then get that "html" with the newly set value.

here is my html

```
<div class="sub_input_box">
  <input type="text" / class="boreder_line">
  <input type="text" id="txt" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" id="hid" />
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and the jquery i used to set attribute

`$("#txt").attr("value", "some value");`

Comment: Please post a complete code example, not a single line of jQuery.

Comment: You should not split the **JavaScript**, in title.

Comment: i am not stuck with jquery, but html text field does not reflect the newly set value once you inspect it with firebug, i tried setting the value of an input hidden and it changes when inspected with fire bug and not html text why ..?

Comment: Are you setting the values before or after the HTML inputs?

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you're calling your jQuery code before the HTML input part. You can either place the jQuery stuff below it, or if you don't want to, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txt").attr("value", "some value");
});
```

That will only run when the page is fully loaded.

However, it's unclear if you're using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to load those inputs into your DOM. If so, you need to call `$("#txt").attr("value", "some value");` in the onSuccess callback function which is fired after the AJAX successfully responds.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
  <input name="example" type="text" id="example" 
  size="50" value="MyDefaultText" onfocus="if(this.value=='MyDefaultText')this.value=''"
  onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='MyDefaultText'" />
```

Comment: thanks rahul , document.getElementById("txt").setAttribute("value", "my value"), it changes the default value of the html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$("#txt").val("Hello World!");
```

For **setting** the text value, and,

```
var my_string = $("#txt").val();
```

For **getting** the text value.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: no this dint set the default value in fire bug it show the same previous value

Comment: What's the 'previous value' you would like to set before setting it the first time?

Comment: previous value is either no value or some thing loaded from the template from db via ajax, so it like a junk of html with input text field present  along with other markup

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question. You would think clone would do this on its own, alas, it doesn't.

Here is a sample than you can hopefully adapt to do what you need

> **HTML**

```
<div id=divToCopy>
    <input name=i1 value=foo><br>
    <input name=i2 value=bar>
</div>
<input type=button onclick=copyDiv(); value='Copy the div'>

<div id=newDiv>
    the copy will go here
</div>
```

> **JavaScript**

```
    function copyDiv() {
        $('#newDiv').html($('#divToCopy').clone());

        $('#divToCopy :input').each(function() {
            var child=0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; i++) {
                var attrib = this.attributes[i];
                var prop=$(this).prop(attrib.name);
                $($('#newDiv').find(' :input')[child]).prop(attrib.name,prop);
                child++;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

But it does work: http://jsbin.com/eXEROtU/1/edit

```
var html = '<input type="text" id="txt" value=""/>';

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#load").click(function() {
    $("#sub_input_box").html(html);
  });

  $("#inspect").click(function() {
    alert($("#txt").val());
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('focusout','input[type="text"]',function(a){
console.log(a.target.value);
a.target.setAttribute("value",a.target.value);
});
```

this is the solution i found, i had to set the value attribute explicitly on loose focus from the text field